# mongod.log not clear (ms)

Tags: database, mongodb, logging, insert

0

I cannot understand from documation **what is the meaning of the ms** in the **mongod.log** end of the line I have a replica set with 3 mongo instances.

this is a line from my log:

```
2019-10-30T21:09:41.647Z I COMMAND [co48] command Db.noa command: insert 
{ 
    insert: "noa", 
    ordered: true, 
    $db: "hDb", 
    $clusterTime: {
          clusterTime: Timestamp(1572469780, 646), 
          signature: { 
               hash: BinData(0, 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000), 
               keyId: 0 
          } 
     }, 
     lsid: { 
            id: UUID("91b42ec1-fd1b-4b03-b3d5-fd66e14cc774") 
           } 
     } 
     ninserted:1 
     keysInserted:3 
     numYields:0 
     reslen:214 
     locks:{ 
          Global: { 
               acquireCount: { r: 2, w: 2 } 
          }, 
          Database: { 
               acquireCount: { w: 2 } 
          }, 
          Collection: { 
               acquireCount: { w: 1 } 
          }, 
          oplog: { 
               acquireCount: { w: 1 } 
          } 
     } 
     protocol:op_msg **1056ms**
```

my **write concern is w:1 wtimeout:0**

what it means the acknowledge come after the data is written the memory the ms means the total time to write to disk as well?

please can you help me understand the log

Answer (score 0):

It is a complete client operation time.
It is printed if that time is above the slow operation threshold which is set to 100ms by default.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/log-messages/#log-message-slow-ops

Comment: so its the time that takes to the total operation including writing to disk? and the replica?